# capybara undefined method `tag?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, bdd

I have the following failing test when simply trying to tell Capybara to `visit ('/')`.

```
1) Credits when user is non-enabled show user credits available at the top.
   Failure/Error: visit ('/')
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `tag?' for nil:NilClass
   # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:16:in `set_current_tag'
   # ./spec/requests/credits_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The code in `ApplicationController` looks like this

```
def set_current_site
  current_host = request.host
  @site = Site.where(domain: current_host).first 
  @site = Site.where(domain: 'mysiste.com').first unless @site.present?
end

def set_current_tag
  if @site.tag? && Dvd.tagged_with(@site.tag, wild: true, any: true).any?
    @site.tag = @site.tag
  elsif params[:tag] && Dvd.tagged_with(params[:tag], wild: true, any: true).any?
    @site.tag = params[:tag]
  else
    @site.tag = ''
  end
end
```

I'm a bit lost here in how to solve this and what would be an ideal solution to this. Should I change the design of the instance variables to methods and use FactoryGirl for Site as well?

The Site model is very simple.

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :domain, :content, :program, :tag, :locale, :parent, :title, :landing

  validates_presence_of :domain
  validates_uniqueness_of :domain

end
```

And the factory is

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :site do
    domain    "dvdstore.com"
    title     "DVD Store" 
    program   "premium"
    content   "movies"
  end
end
```

Comment: @Trace please see updated question with Site model.

Comment: You dont have a self.tag? method in your Site model....where are you getting this

Comment: Have you created a site with domain `'mysiste.com'` in the spec?

Comment: @dimuch I did. Please see my updates question with the factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to credits_spec.rb :

```
before do
  @site = FactoryGirl.create(:site)
  @request.host = @site.domain
end
```

By default, request host is 'www.example.com', guess you don't have a site record for this domain.

The fallback for not found site (`@site = Site.where(domain: 'mysiste.com').first unless @site.present?`) probably does not work too:

1. It relies on db entry with domain "mysiste.com", but each test starts with empty DB by default. Have you created such entry?
2. There is probably typo in domain name: `mysiste.com` instead of `mysite.com`

So when you run your spec, @site is not fount and not set.

Comment: Ended up figuring it out mostly at the same time than you replied. Thanks!